# Админка для самописного сайта

Tags: php

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли какая-нибудь инструкция, как сделать админку для самописного сайта?

Comment: Может я не умею пользоваться поиском,но не нашел ничего нормального.
Поэтому решил спросить у знающих людей.

Comment: >но не нашел ничего нормального
решил спросить может у кого завалялось самописная CMS которым поделитесь.

Возьми уже готовую CMS и у неё будет админка.

Comment: @Palmervan, в честь праздника просто удалил)

Comment: @Sh4dow я и сам могу удалить) но я думаю что это не добавит ясности в этой довольно темной ситуации!

Как не есть,  а минус заслуженый!

@Sh4dow понимаю, должок за мной по поводу удаления)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете выбрать альтернативный подход к любому самописному софту. Например:

1. Если есть какой-либо рабочий аналог, скачиваете и очень подробно изучаете. Изучив, решаете для себя, что для вас  необходимо и реализуете. С таким подходом вы не только сможете понять, что надо реализовать, но и то, как это сделать.
2. Если аналога нет, ищите наиболее смежный проект и следуете пункту 1.

Открытых движков с админкой более чем достаточно.

Comment: @Expert не приходило на ум что человек сам не понимает о чем спрашивает?

Я не в обиду, а в концепцию...

Comment: Не думаю. Бывают моменты, когда и простые вопросы могут поставить в тупик. Подход вырабатывается со временем. А вообщем, если участник спросил, значит ему что-то не ясно. Отправлять его далеко не стоит. Если у Вас есть мысли по теме, ответьте участнику. Если Вы считаете, что вопрос не уместен, для этого есть инструменты модерации. Подробнее читайте в [блоге](http://blog.hashcode.ru/2012/01/blog-post_20.html)

Comment: @Expert суть в том что есть определенная структура кода, и к этой структуре кода не привяжишь админку от Joomla(простите что упомянул) или Bitrix? или или... Отталкиваясь от вопроса о просьбе инструкций, вообще стоит умалкивать, ибо ТС не готов к поглощению и восприятию возможно предоставленной участниками ХэшКода для реализаци в тех или иных целях! К чему все и сводится!..

Готовых решений нет, котрые автоматически подстроятся под любой быдлокод и сделают сделают админку и все полезности! Это и нужно понять уважаемому ТС'у.

Comment: @Palmervan согласен с тобой

Answer (score 1):

Не понимаю, зачем инструкция. Делаете веб-морду для быстрого совершения тех действий, которые вы раньше делали через phpMyAdmin (чтобы, например, с id не заморачиваться) и закрываете к ней доступ. Все вопросы безопасности, удобства интерфейса и проч. гуглятся в частном порядке.